# Selenium найти элемент на странице

Tags: python, selenium

Есть сайт - https://r7-office.ru/downloads

Нужно получить название доступных ОС.

Вот html с содержание названия одной из них.

```
<a class="tn-atom" href="#1_2">РОСА Линукс</a>
```

Название этого класса встречается у многих элементов, так что поиск по классу отпадает.

Хардкодить каждое название ОС через поиск по xpath не хочется, так как надо будет добавлять в случае чего еще один путь для нового названия.

Comment: Там же есть ссылка "Перечень поддерживаемых дистрибутивов"

Comment: Это да, но решение должно быть в виде ['Альт Линукс', 'РОСА Линукс', 'Astra Linux', 'РЕД ОС'] и с этой странице